# Maven dependency with older spring boot version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Is it somehow possible to use Maven dependency with older Spring Boot version? The project is using version 2.x and the custom dependency uses 1.5.x. 
Could not found any documentation on the topic.

I'm asking because of getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` while introspecting class inside the custom jar file.

Comment: share your pom.xml and elaborate more on the exact place of issue

Answer (score 2):

No. Spring Boot 2.X is a major version which is not backwards compatible with Spring Boot 1.5.X. Same goes for major Spring Framework versions, you can't mix Spring Framework 5.X and 4.X.

Maven only manages project dependencies. It has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there can only be one version of any given combination of groupId and artifactId in any maven project. So with plain vanilla maven, the answer is 'No'. But there is the maven-shade-plugin that can be used to change the group- and artifact ids of any dependency.